# Transforming from spherical coordinates to Cartesian coordinates using Eigen

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, coordinate-system, eigen

I need to transform the coordinates from spherical to Cartesian space using the Eigen C++ Library. The following code serves the purpose:

```
const int size = 1000;
    Eigen::Array<std::pair<float, float>, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> direction(size);
    for(int i=0; i<direction.size();i++)
    {
            direction(i).first = (i+10)%360; // some value for this example (denoting the azimuth angle)
            direction(i).second = (i+20)%360; // some value for this example (denoting the elevation angle)

     }

    Eigen::MatrixX<T1> transformedMatrix(3, direction.size());
    for(int i=0; i<transformedMatrix.cols(); i++)
    {
        const T1 azimuthAngle = direction(i).first*M_PI/180;    //converting to radians
        const T1 elevationAngle = direction(i).second*M_PI/180; //converting to radians

        transformedMatrix(0,i) = std::cos(azimuthAngle)*std::cos(elevationAngle);
        transformedMatrix(1,i) = std::sin(azimuthAngle)*std::cos(elevationAngle);
        transformedMatrix(2,i) = std::sin(elevationAngle);
    }
```

I would like to know a better implementation is possible to improve the speed. I know that Eigen has supporting functions for Geometrical transformations. But I am yet to see a clear example to implement the same. Is it also possible to vectorize the code to improve the performance?

Note: This is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51555759/efficiently-transforming-from-spherical-coordinates-to-cartesian-coordinates-usi) posting. I think that the question will be more relevant on this site.

Comment: Don't post the exact same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @MikeBorkland I agree with you. But only after posting it on StackOverflow, I realised that the question may be more relevant here! Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not really much to review here. While I have some experience with Eigen, I have no idea what SSPL is. I'm going to assume `SSPL:MatrixX` is basically `Eigen::Matrix3Xf`.

```
const int size = 1000;
```

This should probably use `constexpr` rather than `const`.

```
for(int i=0; i<direction.size();i++)
```

It's been a while since I've used Eigen, but I believe you have a bug in this `for` prologue. If I recall, the return type of `size()` for `Array` types is not `int`. I *think* it is actually `std::ptrdiff_t` (or possibly `std::size_t`), but it's user-customizable. If it is `std::ptrdiff_t` (for example), and `std::ptrdiff_t` is larger than `int` (as it is on some platforms, I think including 64-bit Windows), then you will get UB if the values get cut off.

The way to fix this is to use `decltype`:

```
for (decltype(direction.size()) i = 0; i < direction.size(); ++i)
```

Now the first loop is just generating test data, so let's skip down to the next loop.

```
const T1 azimuthAngle = direction(i).first*M_PI/180;    //converting to radians
```

What's infinitely better than:

```
auto y = /* expression with x */; // convert x to foo
```

is:

```
auto y = convert_to_foo(x);
```

In other words, since you're converting to radians, you should have:

```
constexpr auto to_radians(float v) noexcept
{
    return (v * pi<float>) / 180.0f;
}
```

Now, in addition, `M_PI` is not actually portable. If you don't care, fine, but if you care about portability, you can define a π constant either as:

```
constexpr auto pi = 3.14159265358979f;
```

or, better, as:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr auto pi = T(3.14159265358979L); // add as many digits of precision as you please
```

in which case you can even make the conversion function a template:

```
template <typename T>
// possibly constrain T
constexpr auto to_radians(T const& v) noexcept((v * pi<T>) / T(180))
{
    return (v * pi<T>) / T(180);
}
```

Any way you do it, you should end up with:

```
const T1 azimuthAngle = to_radians(direction(i).first);
const T1 elevationAngle = to_radians(direction(i).second);
```

Now in the next few lines you need the sin and cos of the azimuth and elevation. You might as well precalculate them - especially since you reuse some of them:

```
auto const cos_azimuth = std::cos(azimuthAngle);
auto const sin_azimuth = std::sin(azimuthAngle);
auto const cos_elevation = std::cos(elevationAngle);
auto const sin_elevation = std::sin(elevationAngle);

transformedMatrix(0,i) = cos_azimuth * cos_elevation;
transformedMatrix(1,i) = sin_azimuth * cos_elevation;
transformedMatrix(2,i) = sin_elevation;
```

But transforming coordinate systems seems both like something you can reuse and - more importantly - something you can test in isolation. So this should be a function:

```
template <typename Pair>
auto spherical_to_cartesian(Pair const& spherical)
{
    const auto azimuthAngle = to_radians(std::get<0>(spherical));
    const auto elevationAngle = to_radians(std::get<1>(spherical));

    auto const cos_azimuth = std::cos(azimuthAngle);
    auto const sin_azimuth = std::sin(azimuthAngle);
    auto const cos_elevation = std::cos(elevationAngle);
    auto const sin_elevation = std::sin(elevationAngle);

    return std::tuple{cos_azimuth * cos_elevation, sin_azimuth * cos_elevation, sin_elevation};
}
```

Which makes your loop:

```
for (decltype(transformedMatrix.cols()) i = 0; i < transformedMatrix.cols(); ++i)
{
    std::tie(
            transformedMatrix(0, i),
            transformedMatrix(1, i),
            transformedMatrix(2, i))
        = spherical_to_cartesian(direction(i));
}
```

Now, if you're asking about how to do geometric transforms with Eigen, that seems more like a Stack Overflow question. As for vectorization, that depends on what `SSPL::MatrixX` is. But the loop above can be very easily parallelized, because each transform is independent. As for how, the standard way would require that `Eigen::Array` and `SSPL::MatrixX` could be used with standard algorithms, in which case the answer would simply be:

```
// Hypothetical code.
std::transform(std::par_unseq, begin(direction), end(direction), begin(transformedMatrix), spherical_to_cartesian);
```

Or you could look into OpenMP and parallel `for`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As you guessed correctly it was Eigen::Matrix3Xf. Please also comment whether I can use some vectorization for calculating the "sin" and "cos". I forgot  to mention that I need to use C++ 11 only. Hence I will not be able to use std::par_unseq.

Comment: Is it advisable to copy the azimuth and elevation into Eigen::VectorX so that I can get vectorization advantages?

Comment: @Soo It has been a *long* time since I dealt with SSE, but I don't think it will help you at all because (last time I checked) there are no sin/cos operations. Your biggest gain will probably be with parallelization, not vectorization.